# ajax not firing on change to contenteditable cell

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a contenteditable table which when edited should update a table in the database via ajax but nothing is happening to the database when I change the values.

```
<div id="activities2" class="activities2">  <?
            $q2a="SELECT activityid, activitynumber, title, description, leaders, time FROM activities where activities.meetingid='$id' AND activities.unitid='$input2'";
            $r2a=mysqli_query($dbc,$q2a) or die(mysqli_error($dbc));
            echo "<table class='layouttable'><tr><td>ActivityNumber</td><td>Title</td><td>Description</td><td>Leaders</td><td>Time</td><td>Edit</td>";
            while($row2a   
            =mysqli_fetch_assoc($r2a))  
            {
                echo "
                <tr>
                <td contenteditable='true' id='activitynumber:"  . $row2a['activityid'] .  "'>"  . $row2a['activitynumber'] .  "</td>
                <td contenteditable='true' id='title:"  . $row2a['activityid'] .  "'>" . $row2a['title'] . " </td>
                <td contenteditable='true' id='description:"  . $row2a['activityid'] .  "'>" . $row2a['description'] . " </td>
                <td contenteditable='true' id='leaders:"  . $row2a['activityid'] .  "'>" . $row2a['leaders'] . " </td>
                <td contenteditable='true' id='time:"  . $row2a['activityid'] .  "'>" . $row2a['time'] . " </td>
                </tr>.
                ";
            }
        echo"</table>"; ?><br><Br></div>
```

The javascript for ajax is:

```
<script name = 'inlineedit'>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("td[contenteditable=true]").blur(function(){
       var msg = $(".alert");
       var newvalue = $(this).text();
       var field = $(this).attr("id");
       $.post("activityupdate.php",field+"="+newvalue,function(d){
           var data = JSON.parse(d);
           msg.removeClass("hide");
            if(data.status == '200'){
                msg.addClass("alert-success").removeClass("alert-danger");
            }else{
                msg.addClass("alert-danger").removeClass("alert-success");
            }
           msg.text(data.response);
           setTimeout(function(){msg.addClass("hide");},3000);//It will add hide class after 3 seconds
       });
   });
});
</script>
```

and the php file doing the editing (though it doesnt seem to be getting this far is:

```
<?
$response = NULL;
$status = http_response_code(406);
if(!empty($_POST)){
    include "connect_db.php"; //Including Database Settings
    foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){
        $key = strip_tags(trim($key));
        $value = strip_tags(trim($value));
        $explode = explode(":",$key);
        $activity_id = $explode[1];
        $field_name = $explode[0];
        if(isset($activity_id)){
            $query = "UPDATE activities SET $field_name='{$value}' WHERE activityid='$activity_id'";
            $update = mysqli_query($dbc,$query) or die(mysqli_error($dbc)); //Update the activity Table
            if($update){
                $response = "User Details Updated";
                http_response_code(200); //Setting HTTP Code to 200 i.e OK
            }else{
                $response = "Not Modified";
                http_response_code(304); //Setting HTTP Code to 304 i.e Not Modified
            }
        }else{
            $response = "Not Acceptable";
        }
    }
}
echo json_encode(array(
    "status"=>$status,
    "response"=>$response
));
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need few changes in code:

1. Instead of setting contenteditable='true' use class='editable'.
2. in the js try using on change instead of blur.

   `$("td.editable").on ("change",function(){....`

   this would execute ajax on every change in the editable fields.

Comment: I've tried this and still no luck - looked in the console and no errors in the page anywhere near any of the bits of code that I'm using for this.

Comment: Also easiest way to debug this to step through your javascript code.  using deveoper tools put a breakpoint on the first line of your js function and try to step through it.